# Changing the Layout/Look of the app via Settings in Kotlin/Android

Tags: layout, kotlin

I'm trying to let the user change the layout of the Main Activity via settings. So for example someone can select the newest layout or the original older layout. What would be the best way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All your layouts should have the same number of views, with the same IDs.

If you do so, then you can have a `ConstraintLayout` as the root layout, and create clones of the layout with the child items arranged in different ways. Then, based on the setting, you would apply the constrains from a specific layout to the master layout.

[Check this for reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet)

```
Context context = this;
mConstraintSet2.clone(context, R.layout.state2); // get constraints from layout
setContentView(R.layout.state1);
mConstraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
mConstraintSet2.applyTo(mConstraintLayout)
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks. I'm a bit of a newbie and I think I don't fully understand how to implement this. Not sure how to implement this via settings. But thanks anyway :)